# Maven nexus v=LATEST not working

Tags: maven, repository, nexus

I have maven nexus local repository, on run time i download/fetch jar/war file from maven repo and copy it to tomcat.
I am using following url to to download jar/war file.

```
http://localhost/maven/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.rdc.app&a=rum&v=LATEST&p=war&c
```

When i pass param v=1.2.4 i can download the specific version of war, if i want latest version i found that v=LATEST will return latest version of jar/war file in the repo.

Problem is latest version in maven repo is 12.53.3 when i use v=LATEST it is downloading 12.46.1 i to update 12.53.3 again and tried again v=LATEST but result was same as before.

Also if latest jar is SNAPSHOT other then release jar/war v=LATEST only support release version.

I tried following documentation but seems it is not working.

```
repository.sonatype.org/nexus-core-documentation-plugin/core/docs/rest.artifact.maven.redirect.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question and answer is now 6 years old. Please note that sonatype has a new version of Nexus with a revised backend.

Here is the updated link the the documentation on scheduled tasks, one of which is "Rebuild Maven Metadata Files":

- [Managing scheduled tasks](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager2/configuration/managing-scheduled-tasks)

  ---

## Original answer

Sounds like a meta data problem.
Nexus has a [scheduled task](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-tasks.html) which can be used to rebuild your repository's metadata.

Comment: The link does not work any more. Can you describe this task so I can find it?

Comment: @neves Hope that helps

Answer (score 6):

This is sort of a bug, if you ask me. I have faced it as well.

Basically, LATEST version doesn't mean "latest version" as is in 1.2.3 compared to 1.2.2, it means "the version of the artifact which was most recently deployed". So -- if you have more than one branch of the project and the artifacts are being deployed by your continuous integration server, you can't trust LATEST.

UPDATE: Check Tari aka Manga's reply, for an updated behavior in Nexus.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree.
Sonatype Nexus™ 2.11.2-0, LATEST will point to the highest version available, considering both releases and snaphots.
I just did some test to confirm the behavior.

Comment: @TariakaManga, this has been true for many years. You would have to explain your scenario/setup first, before I could agree. If you could show me the respective `maven-metadata.xml` file, that would be great. Ivan Voroshilin has now deleted his answer which was also very useful as it was pointing to https://support.sonatype.com/entries/23778606.

Comment: fair enough, example with `maven-metadata.xml` provided as separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Some have suggestes (e.g.: @carlspring) that "LATEST" actually does not point to the highest version available, considering both releases and snaphots; they suggest is the most-recently deployed, but I disagree.
This is what happens with Sonatype Nexus™ 2.11.2-0:

Assuming to start with:

```
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>versioningtest</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</latest>
        <release>1.0.1</release>
        <versions>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20150928081006</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

(A)
Publishing a new 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT only increments the "lastupdated" timestamp, it does NOT change the "latest".

Now publishing 1.0.3:

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>versioningtest</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>1.0.3</latest>
        <release>1.0.3</release>
        <versions>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20150928081408</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

(B)
From here, publishing a new 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT only increments the "lastupdated" timestamp, it does NOT change the "latest".
Also, publishing 1.0.2 only increments the "lastupdated" timestamp, it does NOT change the "latest":

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>versioningtest</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>1.0.3</latest>
        <release>1.0.3</release>
        <versions>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20150928081620</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

So in conclusion:

- between two snapshots, even if a younger comes being more recent, the oldest published would win the LATEST spot if it has a higher version. (A)
- between release Vs snapshot, the higher version win the LATEST spot. (B)

Hence, Sonatype Nexus™ 2.11.2-0, "LATEST" point to the highest version available, considering both releases and snaphots.

Q.E.D.

Comment: You seem to have missed my point. You can have two branches of your code producing different versions. Consider the following example: branch `1.x` produces `1.0.1` ... `1.0.n` and branch `1.1.x` produces `1.1.1` ... `1.1.n`. Now deploy a versions `1.0.1` and `1.0.2`, then deploy `1.1.1` and `1.1.2` and then deploy `1.0.3`. At this point `1.0.3` will be the `LATEST`, because it was deployed much more recently.

Comment: Furthermore, if this repository is a group repository (or know as just virtual in Artifactory), your metadata will be merged from both repositories and will contain both SNAPSHOT-s and releases. Based on the scenario described above, you cannot rely on LATEST.

Comment: Dear @carlspring thank you for your feedback, but sorry again I disagree. I've tried push `1.1.0` and it moved correctly release and latest pointer to `1.1.0` as expected. Now, accordingly to your comments, if I push `1.0.4` it would move the latest pointer, but this was NOT the case, I just tried, also I pushed `1.0.5`, no change at all, it just rendered the below.

Comment: `<metadata>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>versioningtest</artifactId>
        <versioning>
            <latest>1.1.0</latest>
            <release>1.1.0</release>
            <versions>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
(...)
                <version>1.0.4</version>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </versions>
            <lastUpdated>20150928085117</lastUpdated>
        </versioning>
    </metadata>`

Comment: So sorry, I don't think I've missed your point, I can understand maybe it does not work in your scenario, but in my out-of-box Nexus installation the LATEST pointer behaves as much expected, to the highest version available, considering both releases and snaphots.
With regards and respect,

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to put down a detailed reply. This seems to be a change in behavior, as earlier versions didn't seem to behave this way. I'm a long time Nexus user. I've had to maintain an Artifactory for the past half-year and it seems like there have been some improvements in Nexus! :) +1.